# how can execute store procedure step by step in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Debugging Stored Procedure in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793612/debugging-stored-procedure-in-sql-server-2008)

Is this possible that we can execute Store Procedure Step by Step in `SQL SERVER 2008` Like Visual Studio .NET code ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible.

1) In your query window type `EXEC YourProcedureName 'Param1', 'Param2'`

2) Press F11 - continuously

3) Check the "Locals" window and check the values of your parameters and declared variables

4) You can right-click variables and click "Add Watch"

Comment: That will return result not give us time to check what value are passing in every steps

Comment: Just give it a try... keep on pressing F11. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can (provided you have at least the professional version of visual studio), although it requires a little setting up. Once you've done this, it's not much different from debugging code. [MSDN has a basic walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yet1b7by%28VS.80%29.aspx).

**Source:** [Debugging Stored Procedure in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793612/debugging-stored-procedure-in-sql-server-2008)