# Debugging stored procedure in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Debugging Stored Procedure in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793612/debugging-stored-procedure-in-sql-server-2008)

I wanted to debug the stored procedure in sql server. I tried with break points, but that didn't work for me. I searched in stack over flow even but din't get proper answer. My procedure is as follows,

```
USE [Practice]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER procedure [dbo].[selectsample]
@input varchar(100),
@output int output
as
begin 
select @output=id
from people where name=@input order by id desc  
end
```

What is the best way to debug this stored procedure?

Comment: What I usually do for a procedure this size is simply execute it a couple times with different arguments.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682112/how-can-execute-store-procedure-step-by-step-in-sql-server/14682143#14682143

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793612/debugging-stored-procedure-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: Thanks a lot DON , the steps helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding top 1 to your query. You have one output patameter but your query can return multiple values (what if there are more people that meet name=@input criteria)