# SQL Server Stored Procedure with cursor

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, scheduled-tasks

I have following stored procedure which basically uses cursor to get people who have appointments today and sends them email. For some reason this query won't complete. When I try to execute it, it just spins and I had to stop it. I let it run for as long as 7 minutes once and still I didn't get either an error or timeout. Not sure what it is doing. Any help will be appreciated. Here is my query:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spReminderEmail] 
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR
DECLARE @emailBody nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @subject nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @recipients nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @appointmentDate datetime
DECLARE @doctorFirstName nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @doctorLastName nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @groupName nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @location nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @count int

SET @count = 0

SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD For
Select StartTime, PersonEmail, DoctorFirstName, DoctorLastName, GroupName, Location  from vwAppointment where StartTime BETWEEN CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AND IsActive = 1

Open @MyCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor INTO @appointmentDate, @recipients, @doctorFirstName, @doctorLastName, @groupName, @location

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN
    SET @emailBody = 'Hello from ' + @groupName + '. This is an email reminder of your appointment with ' + @doctorFirstName + ' ' + @doctorLastName + ' on ' + convert(varchar, @appointmentDate, 1) + ' at ' + @location + '.' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'To help facilitate the meeting, please remember to bring with you any relevant documents (ID, insurance, etc.) and be prepared with questions for the office.' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'If you are unable to make the appointment, please call ' + @groupName + ' or return to KSUAdvising and use the cancellation function. Cancellations are requested at least a day in advance.' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'Late Policy:' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'some text here...';
    SET @subject = 'REMINDER: Your Appointment with the ' + @groupName;
    SET @count = @count + 1     
END
CLOSE @MyCursor
DEALLOCATE @MyCursor

PRINT @count

if (@count > 0)
BEGIN
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name='my_profile',
    @recipients=@recipients,
    @body=@emailBody, 
    @subject=@subject
END
```

Comment: Have you tried running the query outside of the stored procedure?

Comment: You need a FETCH NEXT inside your WHILE loop.

Comment: If it was working fine and all of a sudden stopped working, it is likely a statistics issue or the sproc needs recompiled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the WHILE loop (before END line) you must add this:

```
FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor INTO @appointmentDate, @recipients,
  @doctorFirstName, @doctorLastName, @groupName, @location
```

to scroll for every loop a record of your query

Answer (score 1):

You're never fetching your next row.  So your loop will go on forever doing nothing.  You need to add `FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor INTO @appointmentDate, @recipients, @doctorFirstName, @doctorLastName, @groupName, @location` right before your END statment .  See the example at the bottom of [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You also may try to [debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793612/debugging-stored-procedure-in-sql-server-2008) your sp to find exact place of issues in you SP in the future.